# Configuring SLURM to minimize time in queue for high-priority jobs

Tags: slurm

What is the best way to configuring the queue so that high-priority jobs get started with specified maximum delay?

Imagine a scenario, where one user would submit a lot of jobs with low priority (e.g. after a reboot of the system), which all starts at the same time.
Then another user comes and submits a job. Even if that job has a higher priority than any of the queuing or running jobs, it would have to wait for a long time until a node is free before it can start.

The ignorant way would be to limit the maximum duration of jobs. (e.g. if jobs can run for just 1 hour, then the maximum time high-priority jobs would have to wait would be 1 hour). But that is not a very good solution, since some jobs by nature have to gone on for a long time without being interrupted.

A better solution would be to stagger the start of jobs (or to have a dynamic maximum duration of jobs) so that nodes will free-up at a regular interval.

Is it possible to configure SLURM in this way? If so, how? Optimally, one should be able to say that e.g. during office hours there should at maximum be 30 minutes between nodes freeing up.